# Restoring Windows deleted all my data, any way to recover it?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have two users on my HP Pavilion g6 Notebook(laptop), one of them is a Standard and the other Admin.  Some months ago I had forgotten my admin account password which made working on the laptop difficult so I decided to try to recover Windows as I didn't think it would be a problem.

When the recovery process finished, I opened my computer and saw all of my partitions had disappeared. I had a lot of data stored on the other partitions which was very important to me.

Is there any way to recover my lost data?

Comment: If you want to recover files I say go for photorec. It does it with almost 100% reliability. But beware when i used it once it overwhelmed my drive recovering data which was years old but if you want to recover data photorec is best

Answer (score -1):

From your description, it sounds like the recovery you did is the kind that formats your hard disk and re-installs an image of windows to bring it back to the state it was in when it left the factory. This is not an appropriate action for when you have forgotten a password.

It is possible, but unlikely, that files can be recovered from your hard disk now.

Comment: I suggest a file recovery tool. I cannot suggest which one as it has been a long time, though you will probably have to do it on another P.C with the drive attached. Also, don't use the computer much as files moved around may overwrite areas that are recoverable.

Answer (score -2):

These can work but it can take time.
They work along the same lines.
From:
[Superuser Q](https://superuser.com/questions/87679/recover-data-from-hard-drive-with-partitions-but-not-most-data-overwritten?rq=1),
[Wikipedia,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_recovery_software)
[PcSupport](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm)
From  *softwarerecs.stackexchange.com*
[File-recovery-software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/251/file-recovery-software/1523#1523)
If you have a Portable usb look it up and copy the new install,
so you have a copy just in case.

Comment: Bunch of links are not helpful