# recovering any possible files after partially overwriting partition and partition table

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, ext4

My question is along the lines of "format c:" after making jokes about it for decades... I had a secondary hard-drive 1TB ext4, formatted as a single partition - it was "slower but larger data" storage in my laptop, in a swapable bay in place of the DVD drive. Forgetting that the device letters had changed for a USB thumbdrive, when the drive was in place, I used dd to write a linux install iso to the thumbdrive and accidentally sent it to the 1TB drive. Most of the drive contents is photography, design documents (svf, xcf, pdf, jpg, png, dng) and other files related to my work as an artist.

What are the best possible way(s) to try and retrieve those files? I've read posts saying that imaging the drive before trying anything is a good idea, and will do that when I have a chance to get more storage space. Beyond that, what are possible ways to recover my data? Such a small portion of the drive was overwritten - I am hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

First key is **do not** write anything to the drive. This is why people have recommended making an image so that you dismount the original drive and work with the image and don't accidentally write to the drive.

You will need some other storage device to back up to, best to get one bigger than your original since whatever recovery software you use may produce *more* data than the volume of the original drive.

One piece of software I've used in a windows environment with good results that's also available in linux is Photorec.  [Here's is their own step by step guide](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) and [download links](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)

Most of my experience is with Windows environments.  If you have access to one and didn't want to use photorec in linux then I would suggest mounting the drive and using recovery software listed as answers [to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/87679/recover-data-from-hard-drive-with-partitions-but-not-most-data-overwritten?rq=1)